# Unable to play video from Amazon S3 using PreSignedURL in iOS in ReactNative

Tags: ios, react-native, amazon-s3, avfoundation, pre-signed-url

I have a transcoded video in Amazon S3 bucket and have generated a presigned URL to play it on mobile app developed using ReactNative. It is perfectly working on Android, but not on iOS. It is throwing AVFoundationErrorDomain while playing it.

```
<Video
    resizeMode={'contain'}
    source={{uri:myPreSignedURL,type:"mp4"}}
    onError={(err)=>{
     console.log(err)
     }}     
     style={{flex:1}}
     >
</Video>
```

Here is the error :

```
{"error": {"code": -11800, "domain": "AVFoundationErrorDomain", "localizedDescription": "The operation could not be completed", 
"localizedFailureReason": "An unknown error occurred (1718449215)", "localizedRecoverySuggestion": ""}, 
"target": 11939}
```

Could you please guide me?